# Strongly type Bind(Include = **) attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Here is the definition of an action from one of my controllers

```
public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "Email,Password")] Utilisateur utilisateur)
```

I didn't find any way to bind the properties in this way

```
[Bind(Include = "Utilisateur.Email, Utilisateur.Password")]
```

Doing this would benefit from Visual Studio's refactoring capabilities and every other aspect of the "strong binding" that it would create.

Do we have to use a string to tell the `Include` property which fields to bind or is there a way to do what I want, with the object's properties ?

I could not find any similar question with an explicit answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the only way to use the model binder inline, like I want to do it, is by passing the properties names as a string. There is no way, as far as I know, to have strongly typed model binding.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is two type of attribute for Include and Exclude.

if you want some of parameter include in your model then use include attribute.

```
public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "Email,Password")] Utilisateur utilisateur)
```

and if you want exclude the parameter from you object then use the exclude attribute.

```
public ActionResult Login([Bind(Exclude= "Email,Password")] Utilisateur utilisateur)
```

and let me know if you want any more clarity.

Comment: What i am looking for is a way to pass, not a string but the properties themselves with a lambda or a delegate for example. The point would be to have a strong bond between the actual model and the parameters passes in the Bind annotation